# How do I change an attribute for a policy group without having to re-compile all of the policyfiles?

Tags: chef-attributes, chef-policyfile

I am trying to shift from environment files in Chef to using Policyfiles. https://docs.chef.io/policy.html.  I really like the concept, especially since you can include a policy from policy into another, but I am trying to understand how do a simple attribute change.

For instance, if I want to change a globally-used attribute that may be an error message for a problem that is happening now. ("The system will be down for 10 minutes. Thanks for your patience").  Or perhaps I want to turn off some AB testing with an attribute working as a flag.  From what I can tell, the only way I can do this is to change an attribute in the policyfile, and then I need to create a new version of the policy file.

And if the policyfile is an included in many other policyfiles, like in the case of a base policyfile, then I have a lot of work to do for a simple change.

`default['production']['maintenance_message'] = 'We will be down for the next 15 minutes!'`

`default['production']['start_new_feature'] = true`

How do I make a simple change to an attribute that affects an entire policy group?   Is there a simple way to change an attribute, or do I have to move all my environment properties to a data bag??

Answer (score 0):

OK, I used Chef Support and got an answer:  **Nope**.

This is their response:

> "You've called out one of the main reasons we recommend that people use something like Jenkins pipelines to deliver cookbooks to their infrastructure. All that work can be kicked off by a build system recognizing a change in a dependency and initiating new builds for all the downstream consumer jobs.
>
> For what it's worth, I don't really like putting application configurations like that maintenance message example you used in configuration management, I think something like Habitat is a better system for that kind of rapid-change configuration delivery, although you could also go down the route of storing application configuration like that in a system like Hashicorp Vault, Consul, or etcd, and ensuring that whatever apps need to ingest those changes are able to do so without configuration management fighting with the key-value config store.
>
> If that was just an example to illustrate things, ignore the previous comment and refer only to my recommendation to use pipelines to deliver cookbooks, attributes, etc to your infrastructure (and I would generally recommend against data bags these days, but that's mostly a preference thing)."